# How could I conditioally create a _m256d of -1.0 and +1.0 according to _m256i elements being even or odd?

Tags: simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I am quite new to the compiler intrinsincs. I have 4 uint64_t integers which are stored in a _m256i.

```
__m256i vj = _mm256_setr_epi64x(1, 2, 3, 4);
__m256i one = _mm256_set_epi64x(1, 1, 1, 1);
__m256i vf = _mm256_and_si256(vj, one); // vf = {1, 0, 1, 0}
```

And I would like to get a `__m256d res = {1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0}` based on the value of vf like this:

```
double value[2] = {-1.0, 1.0};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    res[i] = value[vf[i]];
```

What should be the best way that I could generate res from both vf and value? Much appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 5):

In the general case where the two `values[2]` you want to select from aren't related like this, just shift (or compare or do whatever) to get a control vector for `vblendvpd` (`_mm256_blendv_pd`), to select a value for each element from two `_mm256_set1_pd()` constant vectors.  But here we can do it even more cheaply.

---

IEEE FP uses a sign/magnitude format, so you just need to set or flip the top of a `1.0` constant to make it `-1.0`, or clear / flip the top bit of `-1.0` to make `+1.0`.  `xor` or `andnot` will be useful here, since you want the clear the sign bit when the low bit of `vj` is set.

There's no need to compute `vf` with an `and`; you want the low bit of the integer element at the top of the element, so isolate it with `<<63` instead of `&1`, which also gets it where you want it.

```
__m256d minus_one_plus_2x_lowbit(__m256i vj)
{
    __m256i shifted = __m256_slli_epi64(vj, 63);     // 0 or 1 in the sign bit
    __m256d minus_one = _mm256_set1_pd(-1.0);
    return  _mm256_xor_pd(minus_one, _mm256_castsi256_pd(shifted));  // flip the sign bit
}
```

This is two cheap instructions, with some CPUs maybe having an extra cycle of bypass delay latency between integer shift and FP XOR, if your compiler doesn't decide to use `vpxor` instead of `vxorpd` anyway.  On Intel Skylake, bypass forwarding between bitwise booleans and FP math instructions depends on what port it happens to dispatch to (p0 or p1, vs. p5), not which flavour of instruction you use.  And it's only at worst 1 cycle of latency; any other way you could do this would be extra instructions that would definitely have latency.